# Selecting of specific rows based on the column that used GROUP BY in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, distinct

This are the records of my table:

```
item_code   |   qty

001             1
001             1
002             2    
002             2  
003             2
004             1
005             3
```

This is my code for SELECTING distinct `item_code` and total count of qty based on `GROUP BY` `qty`:

```
select item_code, sum(qty) as qty
from imp_inv
group by item_code
```

and this is the result:

```
item_code   |   qty

001             2
002             4    
003             2
004             1
005             3
```

What I am struggling for is that how can I select an `item_code` with a where clause of `qty`, this is what I tried:

```
select item_code, sum(qty) as qty
from imp_inv where qty = 2
group by item_code
```

and this is the result:

```
item_code   |   qty

002             2    
002             2  
003             2
```

The code above is only selecting the `item_code` that has the `qty` of 2, What I want is to select an `item_code` based on its total count of the `qty`, This is the result of what I want to have:

```
item_code   |   qty

001             2  
003             2
```

Hope you all understand my question, Thank you for your help.

**UPDATE**

I remove the distinct in all of my select queries.

I change the qty of the item_code to 3.

I change the COUNT to SUM.

Comment: Are you sure you are using `count(qty)` and not `(sum(qty)`? Sample data and results do not match with the queries you show..

Comment: @ypercube: Yes sir, I am using count(qty), and it is working for me.

Comment: @Matthew, is `DISTINCT` required in the query?

Comment: There is no way that `SELECT COUNT(qty) ... GROUP BY item_code` (your first query) will show `4` for `item_code=2`. Not with the data you have shown.

Comment: @ypercube: Hi sir, in my first query, I select the distinct and their total count, I am not using a where clause with item_code = 2, correct me if im wrong sir, thank you for the help.

Comment: Check your data and results again. See this **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/574b32/1)** and explain to us what is different in your data.

Comment: He was using SUM instead of COUNT, but then the second result doesn't match

Comment: @dnoeth: Or he has more rows that he didn't include in the sample.

Comment: @ypercube: I know the mistake you are pointing sir, I updated my question, I have put wrong qty in item_code 005, sorry for that.

Comment: @Matthew: then please do another update and change COUNT to SUM

Comment: @ypercube: I'm sorry for that sir, I'm not that perfect, every person is not perfect, we always commit mistakes. You must know that.

Comment: Really, there is no need to be sorry. You can rollback the mistakes. That's the edit button for. But before you do another edit, can you just check the link above to SQL-Fiddle and wonder/explain why no `4` appears in the result of the 2nd query?

Comment: @ypercube: What do you mean there is no 4 appear? I do not understand clearly, thank you.

Comment: @Matthew: when you got two rows for item_code 002 how can you get 4 as result of a COUNT?

Comment: @dnoeth: Ahh ok now I understand, sorry it my fault again, I'm checking in my pc, I am both using COUNT and SUM in different queries, this is not my actual record thats why I make a sample like this, I paste the wrong code, Now I understand the difference of COUNT and SUM now, sorry for this, I'm Updating my question now, thank you dnoeth and ypercube.

Comment: @Matthew: You still have to correct both actual and current result for your 2nd select.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pls try below:

```
 HAVING count(qty) = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it:

```
select q.item_code, q.qty from 
(select item_code as item_code, count(qty) as qty from imp_inv group by item_code) as q
where q.qty=2
```

Comment: Yes, it my misprint. Fixed.

Comment: Really, all these `DISTINCT` are redundant.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't rename a column to an alias which already exists as a column name, this will be confusing as you just noticed.

**WHERE qty = 2** refers to the the **column** QTY, when you change it to **HAVING qty = 2** it refers to the alias **count(qty) as qty**.

Simply use HAVING and a different name like **count(qty) as cnt**.

Btw, you don't need DISTINCT as it always works on all column and GROUP BY altready returns a distinct list of value.